# Remember Playlist on Refresh

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, jquery-ui

I am working on video site, It has a features of drag and drop and create playlist and many others. I want to remember the dragged items on the page refresh.

Any help, Ideas????
Please help

Comment: you can use HTML5 `localStorage` or `sessionStorage`

Comment: @kartikeya: ok.. let me try this..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Javascript localStorage. It works great, and has more storage capacity than that of cookies. You can place your dragged items or even the HTML div in localStorage which is created after playlist is saved.

To set item in localStorage:

localStorage.setItem("key", "value");

To get item in localStorage:

localStorage.getItem("key");

Comment: how can i check if it is in session? like we do check ...if(!empty($_SESSION)){ code }

Comment: Sorry - I don't get it, we are not using session here. If you want to use the code on session check you can use something like - 

if( isset($_SESSION['key']) ){ add your JS code}

Comment: actually.. i will drag and drop the image in a div, and when i refresh i want the image to be in the dropper div.. If you got me what i am trying to achieve. Reply please

Comment: every time you drop an image in the div, update your localStorage by adding localStorage.setItem("div_html", $("your_div").html()) and when you refresh your page add something like if(localStorage.getItem('div_html')){ $("your_div").html(localStorage.getItem('div_html')) } in document.ready block